# Amazon DynamoDB scan is not scanning complete table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I are trying to scan and update all entry with specific attribute value in my Amazon DynamoDB table, this will be one time operations and the parameter I am querying is not an index.

If I understood right my only option is to perform a scan of whole Amazon DynamoDB table and whenever that entry is encountered, I should update them.

My table size is around 2 GB and my table has over 8.5 million records.

Below is snippet of my script:

```
scan_kwargs = {
    'FilterExpression': Key('someKey').eq(sometargetNumber)
}
matched_records = my_table.scan(**scan_kwargs)

print 'Number of records impacted by this operations: ' + str(matched_records['Count'])
user_response = raw_input('Would you like to continue?\n')

if user_response == 'y':
    for item in matched_records['Items']:
        print '\nTarget Record:'
        print(item)
        updated_record = my_table.update_item(
            Key={
                'sessionId': item['attr0']
            },
            UpdateExpression="set att1=:t, att2=:s, att3=:p, att4=:k, att5=:si",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':t': sourceResponse['Items'][0]['att1'],
                ':s': sourceResponse['Items'][0]['att2'],
                ':p': sourceResponse['Items'][0]['att3'],
                ':k': sourceResponse['Items'][0]['att4'],
                ':si': sourceResponse['Items'][0]['att5']
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
        print '\nUpdated Target Record:'
        print(updated_record)
else:
    print('Operation terminated!')
```

I tested the above script (some values are changed while posting on stackoverflow) in TEST environment (<1000 records) and everything works fine, but when I test them in PRODUCTION environment with 8.5 million records and 2 GB of data. The script scans 0 records.

[image]

Do I need to perform the scans differently and am I missing something? or its just the limitation of "scan" operation in dynamoDB?

Comment: [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) only returns maximum of 1 MB of data and need to continue to call the api by passing `LastEvaluatedKey` to get more and more.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala yes I believe this will work, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your issue is related to how DynamoDB filters data and paginates results. To review what is happening here, consider the order of operations when executing a DynamoDB scan/query operation while filtering.  DynamoDB does the following *in* *this* *order*:

1. Read items from the table
2. Apply Filter
3. Return Results

DynamoDB `query` and `scan` operations return up to 1MB of data at a time. Anything beyond that will be paginated. You know your results are being paginated if DynamoDB returns a LastEvaluatedKey element in your response.

Filters apply after the 1MB limit. This is the critical step that often catches people off-guard. In your situation, the following is happening:

You execute a scan operation that reads 1MB of data from the table.
You apply a filter to the 1MB response, which results in all of the records in the first step being eliminated from the response.
DDB returns the remaining items with a LastEvaluatedKey element, which indicates there is more data to search.
In other words, your filter isn't applying to the entire table. It's applying to 1MB of the table at a time. In order to get the results you are looking for, you are going to need to execute the scan operation repeatedly until you reach the last "page" of the table.

Comment: Yes that could work, how do we identify that it has reached the last page of all 8.5 mil records? Is there any specific json key DynamoDB returns? Wondering will there be a LastEvaluatedKey even for that last page? Thanks for the help

Comment: DynamoDB will return a `LastEvaluatedKey` when there are more pages to fetch.  Once you reach the end of the paginated results, the `LastEvaluatedKey` field will not be present.  More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html